# Create a direct link to a Magento product via Product ID

Tags: php, magento, hyperlink, product

I would like to place a direct link to a magento product without using to pretty urls. Instead of something like this "http://store.d3scene.com/rift-60-days-pre-paid-time-card.html" I would like it to be "http://store.d3scene.com/product/list/id/187/" - or something similar.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is.  Keeping in mind that most Magento systems are heavily customized and this might not work for your particular installation, use URLs in the form of

```
http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/27
http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/[ID HERE]
```

If you're ever wondering about details for a stock Magento page, you can use the free [Commerce Bug](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net) demo page to find your page, and the use the Controller/Request tab to inspect the path information.  (Disclaimer: I own the company that sells the Commerce Bug extension)

You could also turn off URL rewrites in Magento and Magento will generate "not pretty" URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. It should be like this

```
http://store.d3scene.com/product/1729
```

and you can do categories like this

```
http://store.d3scene.com/category/1729
```

You can see some url rewrites used by magento in the following database table.

```
core_url_rewrite
```

Answer (score 0):

For product 187, you can use

http://localhost/magento/catalog/product/view/id/187

As long as the visibility setting for product 187 is set to include "Catalog". It should be either "Catalog" or "Catalog,Search".

Visibility for products is set on the Admin->Products->Catalog->edit product screen.